# WebView being released too many times

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit, foundation

I'm trying to load a webpage in a WebView in order to take a snapshot of the website. The WebView is contained in a temporary window that I create for this purpose. However, shortly after I release the WebView and the temporary window, the WebView is sent another release message, while it has already been deallocated. This is the error message in the debugger with NSZombieEnabled set to YES.

`*** -[WebView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x608000125820`

I can't figure out what is causing the WebView to be released too many times. The thing that makes it extra confusing is that the problem only occurs while loading certain URL's. For example: when trying to take a snapshot of `http://www.google.com` everything is fine, but when using `http://edition.cnn.com` it almost always crashes.

This is what (a simplified version of) the code looks like:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSWindow *tempWindow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WebView *webView;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1200, 695);
    self.tempWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    self.webView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.webView.frameLoadDelegate = self;

    self.tempWindow.contentView = self.webView;

    [[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://edition.cnn.com"]]];
}

#pragma mark - WebFrameLoadDelegate

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    if (frame != [sender mainFrame]) {
        return;
    }

    // take snapshot here...
    [self takeSnapshot];

    // get rid of web view and temp window
    [self.webView stopLoading:nil];
    [self.webView setFrameLoadDelegate:nil];

    self.webView = nil;
    self.tempWindow = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ARC there seems to be problem with retaining/releasing the `WebView` in some situations. From my testings I found out that loading an empty `NSString`in the `mainFrame` of the `WebView` before releasing it should solve the problem.

See also a [short blog entry on this topic](http://batsonar.blogspot.de/2013/01/webview-and-arc.html).

Comment: I'm keeping a strong reference to the web view which I'm setting to nil to demonstrate the problem. Even if I don't keep a strong reference to the web view, the problem occurs

Comment: I have a very similar setup and with a weak WebView it works without crash or leak, so there must be something else.

Comment: Do you use a javascript delegate or similar? I found that that may lead to a retain: http://batsonar.blogspot.de/2013/01/webview-and-arc.html - so if once retained and once not extra retained may explain the shown behavior.

Comment: Thanks! When I call loadRequest with an empty string before nilling out the web view, like you suggested in your blog post, it works. If you edit your answer to include this solution I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: thanks for following up and glad it works for you as well. Took me some time to remember my own blog post again ...